# How can i make a json file with java jsonGenerator?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I try to make this json format:

```
[{"x":1392440400000,"title":"!"},{"x":1392465600000,"title":"!"}]
```

I tried it out with the jsonGenerator

This is my code:

```
JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator g = f.createJsonGenerator(sw);

    while {
     g.writeStartObject();
     g.writeNumberField("x",111111);
     g.writeStringField("title","!");
     g.writeEndObject();
    }

    g.close();
    return "["+sw.toString()+"]";
```

But my output is like that ist like that:
 `[{"x":1392440400000,"title":"!"} {"x":1392465600000,"title":"!"}]`

Can anybody help me to make the correct Json output with a comma between the objects ?

Comment: Looks like you don't provide all the code. I don't see how you can get  your output from what you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ObjectMapper to generate the output.
So this could be something like this.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("x", 1392440400000l);
data.put("title", "!");

HashMap<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data2.put("x", 1392440400000l);
data2.put("title", "!");

List out = new ArrayList();
out.add(data);
out.add(data2);

String val = mapper.writeValueAsString(out);
```

Comment: and in a while loop ?

Comment: how can i change the data in the hashmap: now o get title first and den the x- value. I acctually want to have the x first.

Comment: You cannot change the ordering for the HashMap. If you really need to have the "x" on first, you have to do it with the JsonGenerator. So in this case to make your code work, you need to add g.writeStartArray() ... and g.writeEndArray();

Comment: Actually, you can use java.util.LinkedHashMap if you want to save ordering of the properties in a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using jackson, but for this specific scenario, you need your `g.writeStartObject();` and `g.writeEndObject();` inside the loop. (Because you're essentially trying to create an Array of Objects, right?)

Comment: yes that's closer: but now i get this output: [{"x":1392440400000,"title":"!"} {"x":1392465600000,"title":"!"}]widthout a comma between the objects

Comment: Use gen.writeStartArray(); and gen.writeEndArray();  to get the comma.